# Tables to JSON -> Adding additional object identifiers from <tr> ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using tableToJson, which you may or may not be familiar with, to convert a table to JSON (Ive included the code for it here if you don't know it). Simple enough. The output is entirely as expected and looks like:

```
{"data":[
{"Time":"6:30am - 8:30am","Monday":"","Tuesday":"Maths","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""},
{"Time":"11:15am - 12:45pm","Monday":"Maths","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"English","Thursday":"","Friday":""},
{"Time":"3:00pm - 5:00pm","Monday":"","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"English","Thursday":"","Friday":""},
{"Time":"5:00pm - 7:00pm","Monday":"","Tuesday":"Science","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""},
{"Time":"7:00pm - 9:00pm","Monday":"","Tuesday":"Science","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""}]
}
```

However, I need to expand on it to take the #ids of each `<tr>` so the JSON looks like: (Assuming the table HTML is `<tr id="session 1"></tr>` etc.)

```
{
"data":{
"session 1":{"Time":"6:30am - 8:30am","Monday":"","Tuesday":"sdfsdf","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""},
"session 2":{"Time":"11:15am - 12:45pm","Monday":"sdfsdfsdf","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""},
"session 3":{"Time":"3:00pm - 5:00pm","Monday":"","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""},
"session 4":{"Time":"5:00pm - 7:00pm","Monday":"","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""},
"session 5":{"Time":"7:00pm - 9:00pm","Monday":"","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""}
}
}
```

For reference The code for tableToJson looks like:

```
(function( $ ) {
  'use strict';

  $.fn.tableToJSON = function(opts) {

    // Set options
    var defaults = {
      ignoreColumns: [],
      onlyColumns: null,
      ignoreHiddenRows: true,
      ignoreEmptyRows: false,
      headings: null,
      allowHTML: false,
      includeRowId: false,
      textDataOverride: 'data-override',
      textExtractor: null
    };
    opts = $.extend(defaults, opts);

    var notNull = function(value) {
      return value !== undefined && value !== null;
    };

    var ignoredColumn = function(index) {
      if( notNull(opts.onlyColumns) ) {
        return $.inArray(index, opts.onlyColumns) === -1;
      }
      return $.inArray(index, opts.ignoreColumns) !== -1;
    };

    var arraysToHash = function(keys, values) {
      var result = {},index=0, name = 'test';
      $.each(values, function(i, value) {
        // when ignoring columns, the header option still starts
        // with the first defined column
        if ( index < keys.length && notNull(value) ) {
          result[ keys[index] ] = value;
          index++;
        }
      });
      return result;
    };

    var cellValues = function(cellIndex, cell, isHeader) {
      var $cell = $(cell),
        // textExtractor
        extractor = opts.textExtractor,
        override = $cell.attr(opts.textDataOverride);
      // don't use extractor for header cells
      if ( extractor === null || isHeader ) {
        return $.trim( override || ( opts.allowHTML ? $cell.html() : cell.textContent || $cell.text() ) || '' );
      } else {
        // overall extractor function
        if ( $.isFunction(extractor) ) {
          return $.trim( override || extractor(cellIndex, $cell) );
        } else if ( typeof extractor === 'object' && $.isFunction( extractor[cellIndex] ) ) {
          return $.trim( override || extractor[cellIndex](cellIndex, $cell) );
        }
      }
      // fallback
      return $.trim( override || ( opts.allowHTML ? $cell.html() : cell.textContent || $cell.text() ) || '' );
    };

    var rowValues = function(row, isHeader) {
      var result = [];
      var includeRowId = opts.includeRowId;
      var useRowId = (typeof includeRowId === 'boolean') ? includeRowId : (typeof includeRowId === 'string') ? true : false;
      var rowIdName = (typeof includeRowId === 'string') === true ? includeRowId : 'rowId';
      if (useRowId) {
        if (typeof $(row).attr('id') === 'undefined') {
          result.push(rowIdName);
        }
      }
      $(row).children('td,th').each(function(cellIndex, cell) {
        result.push( cellValues(cellIndex, cell, isHeader) );
      });
      return result;
    };

    var getHeadings = function(table) {
      var firstRow = table.find('tr:first').first();
      return notNull(opts.headings) ? opts.headings : rowValues(firstRow, true);
    };

    var construct = function(table, headings) {
      var i, j, len, len2, txt, $row, $cell,
        tmpArray = [], cellIndex = 0, result = [];
      table.children('tbody,*').children('tr').each(function(rowIndex, row) {
        if( rowIndex > 0 || notNull(opts.headings) ) {
          var includeRowId = opts.includeRowId;
          var useRowId = (typeof includeRowId === 'boolean') ? includeRowId : (typeof includeRowId === 'string') ? true : false;

          $row = $(row);

          var isEmpty = ($row.find('td').length === $row.find('td:empty').length) ? true : false;

          if( ( $row.is(':visible') || !opts.ignoreHiddenRows ) && ( !isEmpty || !opts.ignoreEmptyRows ) && ( !$row.data('ignore') || $row.data('ignore') === 'false' ) ) {
            cellIndex = 0;
            if (!tmpArray[rowIndex]) {
              tmpArray[rowIndex] = [];
            }
            if (useRowId) {
              cellIndex = cellIndex + 1;
              if (typeof $row.attr('id') !== 'undefined') {
                tmpArray[rowIndex].push($row.attr('id'));
              } else {
                tmpArray[rowIndex].push('');
              }
            }

            $row.children().each(function(){
              $cell = $(this);
              // skip column if already defined
              while (tmpArray[rowIndex][cellIndex]) { cellIndex++; }

              // process rowspans
              if ($cell.filter('[rowspan]').length) {
                len = parseInt( $cell.attr('rowspan'), 10) - 1;
                txt = cellValues(cellIndex, $cell);
                for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
                  if (!tmpArray[rowIndex + i]) { tmpArray[rowIndex + i] = []; }
                  tmpArray[rowIndex + i][cellIndex] = txt;
                }
              }
              // process colspans
              if ($cell.filter('[colspan]').length) {
                len = parseInt( $cell.attr('colspan'), 10) - 1;
                txt = cellValues(cellIndex, $cell);
                for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
                  // cell has both col and row spans
                  if ($cell.filter('[rowspan]').length) {
                    len2 = parseInt( $cell.attr('rowspan'), 10);
                    for (j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
                      tmpArray[rowIndex + j][cellIndex + i] = txt;
                    }
                  } else {
                    tmpArray[rowIndex][cellIndex + i] = txt;
                  }
                }
              }

              txt = tmpArray[rowIndex][cellIndex] || cellValues(cellIndex, $cell);
              if (notNull(txt)) {
                tmpArray[rowIndex][cellIndex] = txt;
              }
              cellIndex++;
            });
          }
        }
      });
      $.each(tmpArray, function( i, row ){
        if (notNull(row)) {
          // remove ignoredColumns / add onlyColumns
          var newRow = notNull(opts.onlyColumns) || opts.ignoreColumns.length ?
            $.grep(row, function(v, index){ return !ignoredColumn(index); }) : row,

            // remove ignoredColumns / add onlyColumns if headings is not defined
            newHeadings = notNull(opts.headings) ? headings :
              $.grep(headings, function(v, index){ return !ignoredColumn(index); });

          txt = arraysToHash(newHeadings, newRow);
          result[result.length] = txt;
        }
      });
      return result;
    };

    // Run
    var headings = getHeadings(this);
    return construct(this, headings);
  };
})( jQuery );
```

I'm probably missing something really simple, but honestly cannot see how to do this. Any help would be super appreciated. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Your jsons are not valid. Comma-delimited lists of objects (arrays) are defined in square brackets (`{"data":[{..},{..}`).

Comment: The actual output sorry from a dummy i just ran is:
[{"Time":"6:30am - 8:30am","Monday":"","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""},{"Time":"11:15am - 12:45pm","Monday":"sdfsdfsdf","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""},{"Time":"3:00pm - 5:00pm","Monday":"","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""},{"Time":"5:00pm - 7:00pm","Monday":"","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""},{"Time":"7:00pm - 9:00pm","Monday":"","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":""}]

Comment: so sorry.. that was my cut and paste fail

Comment: Hi Jan, I need it for a certain API endpoint I will be PUTing too. It seems to relies on this as without the above, It will not work. With it PUTs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please *rethink* why you'd need to change it. This already provides valid ordered content in a JSON array (accessible via `foo.data[0]`, `foo.data[1]` etc, or iterable with `for(var i; i<foo.data.length;i++){}`).

What you want will give you something with no guaranteed order (properties order in an object is **irrelevant** in JSON) and goes against the flow).

---

Edit: **Stupid API**.

If you *must* conform to some obscure and evil standard, edit the data after it was created. You can't expect `$.fn.tableToJSON` not to conform to JSON & javascript standards...

```
var foo = // output from $.fn.tableToJSON
var out = {data:{}}; //declare an *object* instead of an array
for(var i = 0; i < foo.data.length; i++){
  out.data['Session ' + (i + 1)] =  foo.data[i];
}
//debug output
console.log(JSON.stringify(out))
```

Comment: I agree with you. Unfortunately, I am PUTTING the JSON to an endpoint that needs this, i guess you can call it a "id" or "name"?

Comment: Yeh that's what I was thinking I had to try to do. Let me test and get back to you. Thank you for the help so far. Super appreciate it

Comment: Boom! That worked a treat and the api loves it. Thank you friend!